# Cast to Int from a VB Collection

Tags: c#, casting

Do you see wrong code in here? I am getting a InvalidCaseException on the foreach loop that is using an INT variable:

```
 Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection oHeaders = GetFieldIdsByName(msREPORT_HEADER);

foreach (int FieldId in oHeaders)
```

Comment: If the items in that collection aren't `int`s, you can't cast them to `int`, which is what the foreach loop is attempting to do. What type of objects are in that collection? (For that matter, why are you using the `VisualBasic.Collection` type instead of the `System.Collections` or `System.Collections.Generic` equivalents?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach (object FieldId in oHeaders)
{
    int value = Int32.Parse(FieldId.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (int i in oHeaders.Cast<int>())
{
     //TODO: your action here.
}
```